# Passing report values to a query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm a novice with Microsoft Access as my background is mostly .NET.  I'm sure what I'm trying to accomplish is dead simple but I need some direction.  I have a report and a query.  The query returns a single numeric value based on a single numeric criteria.

Select total from table where id = [topic]

I have placed a text box on my report so I can feed the id to this query and in return get the total.  It seems like DLookUp is what I want but no matter how I construct it, I get an "#Error" in the text box when I run the report.

Currently my DLookUp looks like this (I just hard-coded now for simplicity):

```
=DLookUp("[total]","myquery","[topic] = 3")
```

How can I pass a value from a field on my report to a query so I can return the query's single numeric value?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the query return the total of the records displayed in the report? If so, you really don't need the query, or a DSum() or DLookup() at all -- you can just Sum() in the footer of the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a query named *myquery*, with a parameter named *topic*:

```
Select total from table where id = [topic]
```

You could change *myquery* to this:

```
Select total from table;
```

Then your DLookUp could be this:

```
=DLookUp("[total]","myquery","id = 3")
```

However, in that case *myquery* isn't much use.  You could DLookUp against the table directly.

```
=DLookUp("[total]","table","id = 3")
```

If instead of 3, you want to substitute a value from a text box, *txtId*, try it this way:

```
=DLookUp("[total]","myquery","id = " & Me.txtId)
```

Incidentally, *table* is not a good choice for the name of a table.  See [Problem names and reserved words in Access](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#T)

Answer (score 1):

The query returns a single value, so you do not need a where statement, so:

```
 =DLookUp("[total]","myquery")
```

You could also use DSum or DCount if you wanted to skip the query, then you would need a where statement. Another odd problem arises when you use a control with the same name as a selected field for anything other than the field.

EDIT re Comment

Let us say that you have a query, AQuery:

```
 SELECT ID, AField FROM ATable
```

You can say:

```
 =DLookUp("Afield","AQuery","ID=" & [ANumericReportField])
```

Or

```
 =DLookUp("Afield","ATable","ID=" & [ANumericReportField])
```

You can also say:

```
 =DSum("ANumericField","ATable","ATextField='" & [ATextReportField] & "'")
```

Comment: how do I pass the criteria value from my report to the query?

Comment: It is a little difficult to say, because I am not sure where `topic` comes into it, or what your query returns, but I will add a general note.